Alembic creates foreign key constraints before other table is created
I'm trying to setup Alembic for the first time.  I dropped all my tables, so that Alembic would be starting from scratch.  I entered
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "Initial tables"
alembic upgrade head

I got an immediate error because it was creating a table which has a foreign key.  But the other table hadn't been created yet.
Here's an extract
def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('calibration_metric',
    sa.Column('pk', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['metric_pk'], ['metric.pk'], ),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('pk')
    )

and then way down, many lines later
  op.create_table('metric',
  sa.Column('pk', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),

Is there a way to tell Alembic not to create the Foreign Key constraints until after all the tables have been created?
Any other solution?

Can't reproduce: if I define these tables they are both created without error. SQLAlchemy is able to construct the dependency graph of FKs; I suspect there is something else going on here.

# ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###

Alembic is recommending that you check and adjust the autogenerated files yourself.
You can move the create_table('metric',...) call above the create_table('calibration_metric',...) call so that the tables are created in a logical order.

Yes, I noticed that.  I was wondering if this is a known problem or if there is some solution to tell Alembic what order to create things.  There are lots of inter-dependencies between my tables, so simply re-ordering them manually would be a big effort.
The easiest solution is to just put all the fk constraint creations after all the table creations.  I'm wondering if there should be any problem doing that.

In my experience, and yours I assume, it adds them from top to bottom when found in your script.
From the documentation, "It is critical to note that autogenerate is not intended to be perfect." https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/autogenerate.html
Another solution could be to add all the tables first, run the migration, then go through and add the foreign key constraints and run that migration. I feel like you know this so I'm just leaving it here for those that want another solution

SQLAlchemy is capable of computing the dependency graph of FKs - I doubt that this is the issue
